# Apple: do affiliate links earn money for in-app purchases?

Tags: app-store, affiliate

Apple recently (within the last month or two) made a bunch of changes to their affiliate program.  Can you answer this question: do affiliate links earn money for in-app purchases?

Example: will an affiliate link to a free app that then results in an in-app purchases in that app earn a commission for the link owner?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about policy approaches by a company and doesn't have any software relevance

Comment: I think the sentence: As an affiliate, you can earn a commission on revenue generated by encoded links. Commissions are eligible on sales for up to 24 hours after a user clicks on your link. - in-app purchases would not appear to be covered with a detail like this

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is "yes" - in-app purchases can earn affiliate commissions.  However, there are a few technical details.

With the new platform (PHG, that took over for LinkShare and DGM on Oct. 1), only in app purchases from within the app that was referred in your affiliate link will be eligible for commissions.

Previously, and still with Tradedoubler, an in app purchase from any app is eligible for a commission.

It's also important to point out that the affiliate window (how long the affiliation lasts for) is/was 72 hours for LinkShare, DGM, and Tradedoubler while it's 24 hours for PHG.

Answer (score 0):

SKStoreProductParameterAffiliateToken

The value of this token is an instance of NSString, representing the affiliate identifier you wish to use for any purchase made through the view controller.

Looks like you can use this.